# Character count in ckEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using below code for Character count of ckEditor.

```
var editorConfig = {
      height: '400px',
      filebrowserUploadMethod: "form",
      filebrowserUploadUrl: "main_blog_upload.php",
      defaultLanguage: "es",
      language: "es",
      enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, // Set to use <br> tags for line breaks
      shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, // Set to use <br> tags for Shift+Enter
      charCountCallback: function(charCount) {
          // Get the data from the editor
          var data = this.getData();

          // Calculate the number of line breaks (only <br> tags are used)
          var lineBreaksCount = (data.match(/<br[^>]*>/g) || []).length;

          // Calculate the character count, excluding line breaks
          var characterCount = data.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').length;

          // Add the character count and line breaks count
          return characterCount + lineBreaksCount;
      }
    };

    // Create CKEditor instance with the merged configuration
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor', editorConfig);


    
  
    function stripHtml(html) {
      var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
      tmp.innerHTML = html;
      return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
    }


    function countWordsAndCharacters() {
      var data = editor.getData();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = data;

      var textOnly = div.textContent || div.innerText || '';

      // Check if textOnly is empty or contains only white spaces
      var wordsArray = textOnly.trim().split(/\s+/);
      var wordCount = (wordsArray.length === 1 && wordsArray[0] === '') ? 0 : wordsArray.length;

      // var characterCount = textOnly.replace(/\s/g, '').length;
      var characterCount = textOnly.length;

      $('#count').text(`${wordCount} words ${characterCount} characters`);
    }
    

    editor.on('instanceReady', () => {
        countWordsAndCharacters();
    });

    editor.on('keyup', () => {
        countWordsAndCharacters();
    });

    editor.on('change', () => {
        countWordsAndCharacters();
    });

    editor.on('key', function(event) {
      var enterKey = 13;
      if (event.data.keyCode === enterKey) {
        var selection = editor.getSelection();
        var ranges = selection.getRanges();
        var range = ranges[0];
        var blockTag = range.startContainer.getAscendant('p', true);
        if (blockTag && range.checkStartOfBlock() && range.checkEndOfBlock()) {
            // Prevent CKEditor default Enter key behavior
            event.cancel();
            // Insert <br> tag manually
            var brElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('br');
            editor.editable().insertElement(brElement);
        }
      }
    });
```

My issue is if I press Enter after a full stop(.) I am getting 2 characters. But I would like to get 1 character.

I am getting 2 characters after pressing `Enter` after below sentence.

`Las aplicaciones de aprendizaje de idiomas están disponibles en línea y ofrecen una amplia variedad de recursos de aprendizaje, desde lecciones interactivas hasta clases en vivo con profesores nativos de inglés.`

I am getting 2 characters after pressing `Enter` after below sentence.

`En este artículo, hemos reunido las 12 mejores aplicaciones para aprender inglés, que pueden ser usadas tanto por niños como por adultos (¡algunas más que otras!)`

I am getting 1 character after pressing `Enter` after below sentence.

`Cada una de estas aplicaciones ha sido cuidadosamente seleccionada para brindarte una experiencia de aprendizaje única y efectiva.`

Why it is happening like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Because line breaks still exist after you hit ENTER. Try this (see the second `replace()` to exclude them for your character count:

`var characterCount = data.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '');`

**Edit:**
And an additional space is added, so you need trim().

```
function countWordsAndCharacters() {
      var data = editor.getData();
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = data;

      var textOnly = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";

      // Check if textOnly is empty or contains only white spaces
      var wordsArray = textOnly.trim().split(/\s+/);
      var wordCount = (wordsArray.length === 1 && wordsArray[0] === "") ? 0 : wordsArray.length;
      textOnly = textOnly.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").trim();

      // var characterCount = textOnly.replace(/\s/g, "").length;
      var characterCount = textOnly.length;

console.log(wordCount + " words "  + characterCount + " characters"); 
    }
```

Gives me `16 words 101 characters` with your sentence `Saber los números en inglés es esencial para cualquier persona que quiera comunicarse en este idioma.` with or without additional `ENTERS`

Comment: Thanks @Peimol. Still I am getting 2 characters if I press `Enter` after below sentence. 

`Saber los números en inglés es esencial para cualquier persona que quiera comunicarse en este idioma.`

Comment: @abuabu I updated my answer (don't know if you receive a notification about it)

Comment: Thanks @Piemol. I am still facing the issue. Actually I am facing strange behavior. Often it is showing 1 character and often it is showing 2 characters. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu then you should use the debugger of your browser to step through the script and see what characters are really in the string and should be ignored for the counting. According to my own findings it's just accurate. See: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/ or https://mozilladevelopers.github.io/playground/debugger/